# Overriding argument type in interface implementation

Tags: php, oop

Let's assume I have a Model Interface:

```
interface Model
{
}
```

And a function in an interface which receives that Model as a param:

```
interface Service
{
    public function add(Model $model);
}
```

Why is it, that when I implement that Service with another Model that implements the above like this:

```
class AnotherModel implements Model
{
}

class AnotherService implements Service
{
    public function add(AnotherModel $model);
}
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Declaration of AnotherService::add() must be compatible
>   with Service::add(Model $model)

Comment: Does AnotherModel inherits from Model ?

Comment: AnotherModel implements Model.

inheritance is from classes or abstract classses.

Comment: That's exactly why this doesn't work.
Model is not an object, so AnotherModel is not a Model object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you extend a class or implement an interface you are not allowed to make any type or visibility constraints of inherited methods more strict than in the parent. It means that if you have a public method in the parent you are not allowed to make it protected/private. And if a parent method accepts arguments of some specific type (**Model** in this case), you are not allowed to limit arguments it accepts to some more specific type.

That's what you are doing here - your **Service::add()** accepts elements of type **Model**, but the implementation in **AnotherService** accepts **ONLY** objects of type **AnotherModel**. It means that even if you have another class that implements **Model**, e.g. "**class YetAnotherModel implements Model**", **AnotherService::add()** won't accept it as YetAnotherModel is not an instance of AnotherModel, even though they implement the same interface.
So **AnotherService::add()** won't accept object of **YetAnotherModel** class even though you implement **Service** interface that says "I accept all Models in my **add()** method".

Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle for more details.

Comment: I see now the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2):

At first, the [documentantion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) says:

> The class implementing the interface must use the exact same method signatures as are defined in the interface. Not doing so will result in a fatal error.

And now, there's a pretty good reason behind this. Interface provides to the programmer information about available methods in all classes implementing that interface. Your `Service` interface promises, that it has `add` method which can handle argument of type `Model`. You can't break that promise by providing implementantion only for particular subset of Models.

Consider yourself as a programmer working with some external library. Typically you're left alone with the library interface and don't want to look at the implementation (that's exactly why interfaces was introduced in PHP). If argument type change had been allowed, then interfaces would have been useless for you, as you would have to look for each implementantion instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to modify the prototype of method `add` originally declared in `Service::add`. When implementing an interface, the prototype of the method must be the same as defined in the interface (`Service` in this example). You have to change `public function add(AnotherModel $model);` with `public function add(Model $model);`. In this way you correctly implements the method's interface. When you have to call this method you can pass objects that are implementing `Model` interface, example:

```
class AnotherService implements Service
{
    public function add(Model $model)
    {
        ...
    }
}

$anotherModel = new AnotherModel();
$anotherService = new AnotherService();

$anotherService->add($anotherModel);
```

Comment: Yes I know this is how it is supposed to work. 
But then how do I, for example, know I am working with AnotherModel for let's say auto type purposes?

Comment: you can check this inside the add method with instanceof operator: if ($model instanceof AnotherModel) .... if i understand your question

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
interface IModel
{
}

class Model implements IModel
{
    // All your models should inherit from this class
}

class AnotherModel extends Model
{
}

interface IService
{
    public function add(Model $model);
}

class AnotherService implements IService
{
    public function add(Model $model)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This code-only answer does not explain to the OP why they are having an error and it does nothing but add another layer of indirection to their existing object graph.

Comment: There is already an accepted answer which explains all the theory. This answer is just an example of how to deal with this problem in practice.